# Parsing a url into host and path

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a program which splits a url into host and path:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  std::vector<std::string> url = parseUrl(argv[1]);

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  int MAXDATASIZE = 1024;
  std::string request = "GET " +url.at(1) + " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
  const char* charRequest = request.c_str();
  char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
  if((status = getaddrinfo(url.at(0).c_str(), "80", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0){
    std::cout << "getaddrinfo: " << gai_strerror(status) << "\n";
    return 2;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Server struct created successfully\n";
  }
  if((sock = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol)) == -1){
    std::cout << "Error creating socket\n";
    return 2;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Successfully created socket\n";
  }
  if(connect(sock, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen) == -1){
    std::cout << "Error connecting to host " << url.at(0) << " at port " << "80" << "\n";
    return 2;
  } else {
      std::cout << "Connected successfully to " << url.at(0) << "at port " << "80" << "\n";
  }
  if((send(sock, charRequest, strlen(charRequest), 0)) == -1){
     std::cout << "Error communicating with website\n";
     return 2;
  } else {
     std::cout << "Sent request successfully to " << url.at(0) << " at port " << "80" << "\n";
  }
  if(recv(sock, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0) == -1){
     std::cout << "Error recciving data from " << url.at(0) << " at port " << "80" << "\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Recieved data successfully from " << url.at(0) << " at port " << "80" << "\n";
  }
  std::ofstream file;
  file.open(argv[2]);
  file << buf;
  file.close();
  close(sock);

  freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
}

 // Returns vector with host as first argument and path as second
  std::vector<std::string> parseUrl(std::string url){
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    size_t dotPos = url.find('.');
    size_t slashPos = url.find('/', dotPos);
    std::string host = url.substr(0, slashPos);
    std::string path = url.substr(slashPos, url.length());
    ret.push_back(host);
    ret.push_back(path);
    return ret;
  }
```

Does anyone have suggestions for improvement. Especially about the clunky vector return?

Comment: The returning of a vector is not that clunky. Because of move semantics the vector will be `moved` back avoiding any copies.

Comment: Your URL parsing is not very accurate and would break on any real url. The host section does is not required to have a `dot` in it. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL. This image I find particularly helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:URI_syntax_diagram.svg but the full definition is here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Comment: Personally I would split a url into:  `schema`, `user`, `host`, `port`, `path`, `query`, fragment` (removing the dividers). Not in the wild a lot of URL are mall formed most browser take this into account. The worst offenders is not having the `?` before the query.

Comment: What does the next function look like that will handle the returned vector?

Comment: I've posted the next function @Mast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `std::vector` and using the indices to specify the host and path, we can create a little struct and refer to the members by name:

```
struct URL
{
  std::string host;
  std::string path;
};
```

So we can refer to `url.host` instead of `url.at(0)`.

---

As pointed out in the comments, the parsing method could be more accurate and comprehensive. It's fine to only support a small subset of the url syntax, but we should at least check that we got what we expected in the string.

In this case, I think we should:

- Throw an error if we don't find a dot.
- Either throw an error if we don't find a slash, OR set the path part of the url to `"/"` to ensure that our `GET` request is valid.

---

```
int MAXDATASIZE = 1024;
...
char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
```

This doesn't compile for me. `MAXDATASIZE` must be a constant.

We can remove the need for a separate constant by using `std::array`:

```
std::array<char, 1024> buf;
// now we can use buf.size() :)
```

---

Even for something small like this, it's probably worth writing our own `socket` class. This provides some cleanup safety (RAII), as well as making the code in `main()` a lot simpler and easier to read by removing some of details of the network code. e.g. something like the following:

```
struct socket
{
public:

    socket();
    explicit socket(struct addrinfo const& address);

    socket(socket const&) = delete;
    socket& operator=(socket const&) = delete;

    socket(socket&& other);
    socket& operator=(socket&& other);

    ~socket();

    std::size_t send(char const* data, std::size_t data_size);
    std::size_t receive(char* buffer, std::size_t buffer_size);

    bool is_open() const;
    void close();

private:

    SOCKET m_handle;
};
```

We could also move the address lookup out of `main()` into a separate function, and keep the `addrinfo` in a unique pointer with a custom deleter that calls `freeaddrinfo()`. Something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<addrinfo, std::function<void(addrinfo*)>> lookup_address(std::string const& node, std::string const& service, int ai_family, int ai_socktype, int ai_protocol, int ai_flags = 0)
{
  auto ai_hints = addrinfo();
  // ... set up hints!

  auto output = (addrinfo*) nullptr;
  auto result = getaddrinfo(node.c_str(), service.c_str(), &ai_hints, &output);
  // ... check errors!

  return { output, [] (addrinfo* ai) { freeaddrinfo(ai); } };
}
```

So we might end up a main like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc != 3)
    throw std::runtime_error("Unexpected argument count!");

  auto url = parse_url(argv[1]);
  auto address = lookup_address(url.host, "80", AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, 0, 0);
  
  if (!address)
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed address lookup!");

  auto s = socket(*address);
  
  if (!s.is_open())
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to connect!");
  
  auto request = "GET " + url.path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
  auto sent = s.send(request.c_str(), request.size() + 1);

  if (sent != request.size() + 1)
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to send request!");

  auto buffer = std::array<char, 1024>();
  auto received = s.receive(buffer.data(), buffer.size());

  if (received == 0)
    throw std::runtime_error("No data received!");

  std::ofstream(argv[2]).write(buffer.data(), received);
}
```

(code not compiled or tested).